# reset ng-model from controller in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a list of editable inputs from a list of items. I want the user to be able to edit any of the items, but if they change there mind they can click a button and reset it back to the way it was.

So far I have everything working except the reset.

my html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <label>Input {{$index+1}}:</label>
    <input ng-model="item.value" type="text" ng-click="copy(item)"/>
    <button ng-click="reset(item)">
    x
    </button>
</div>
{{list}}<br>
{{selected_item_backup}}
</div>
```

my controller

```
function TestController($scope) {

$scope.selected_item_backup = {};

$scope.list = [ { value: 'value 1' }, { value: 'value 2' }, { value: 'value 3' } ];

$scope.reset = function (item) {
    // i know this wont work for many reasons, it is just an example of what I would like to do
    item = $scope.selected_item_backup;
};

$scope.copy = function (item) {
    angular.copy(item, $scope.selected_item_backup);
};
}
```

and here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmc/1ab24o4t/1/

Keep in mind that this is a simplified version of my real code. My objects will have many editable fields each. Also they are not indexed, and so the index cannot be relied on. I just want to be able to assign the original item on top of the new and have it replaced.

Comment: Really not sure what you are trying to accomplish using `click` in input. User can click on an input several times while editing which will overwrite last copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is work solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/c2v9t7n2/1/)

```js
function TestController($scope) {

  $scope.list = [{
    value: 'value 1'
  }, {
    value: 'value 2'
  }, {
    value: 'value 3'
  }];
  var orgiinalList = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.list, function(item) {
    orgiinalList.push(angular.copy(item));
  });

  $scope.reset = function(index) {
    $scope.list[index] = angular.copy(orgiinalList[index]);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <label>Input {{$index+1}}:</label>
    <input ng-model="item.value" type="text" />
    <button ng-click="reset($index)">
      x
    </button>
  </div>
  {{list}}
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however iteration over $scope.list is not required.   `var orginalList = angular.copy($scope.list);` will suffice.

Comment: Thank you. `var orginalList = angular.copy($scope.list);` it's better I remember)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use global functions as controllers in newer versions of angular but you can register your controllers in your application:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <label>Input {{$index+1}}:</label>
        <input ng-model="item.value" type="text" ng-click="copy($index,item)"/>
        <button ng-click="reset($index,item)">
        x
        </button>
    </div>
    {{list}}<br>
    {{selected_item_backup}}
```

```
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.selected_item_backup = [];   
  $scope.list = [ { value: 'value 1' }, { value: 'value 2' }, { value: 'value 3' } ];
  $scope.reset = function (index) {      
    $scope.list[index].value = $scope.selected_item_backup[index];
  };

  $scope.copy = function (index,item) {
    // backup the old value
    $scope.selected_item_backup[index] = item.value;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your reset function so that it looks like this:

```
$scope.reset = function(index) {
    $scope.list[index].value = "value "+ (index+1); 
};
```

will make it so that your 'reset' buttons restore what would be those original values...

Angular controller:

```
function TestController($scope) {

  $scope.selected_item_backup = {};

  $scope.list = [{
    value: 'value 1'
  }, {
    value: 'value 2'
  }, {
    value: 'value 3'
  }];

  $scope.reset = function(index) {
    $scope.list[index].value = "value " + (index+1);
  };

  $scope.copy = function(item) {
    angular.copy(item, $scope.selected_item_backup);
  };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <label>Input {{$index+1}}:</label>
    <input ng-model="item.value" type="text" ng-click="copy(item)" />
    <button ng-click="reset($index)">
      x
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The values of your array are directly modeled by those inputs - therefore as a user types changes into those inputs they are directly manipulating the $scope.list array so you cant really use it as a reference... Hope that makes sense.